# How to include non zero values in a dataframe column?

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

I have a dataframe in which out of various columns there is a quantity column.

This column has some entries with zero.

I want to drop rows from the dataframe which has quantity as zero, like-

df[quantity] = df[quantity > 0]

Is the above approach is correct or any better way to do so?

Comment: If you want to exclude rows where quantity == 0, use `df = df[df['quantity'] != 0]`.

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly I wanted.